# Programmatically focus on a form element after mounting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form component (FormComponent) that I need to programmatically focus on when a sibling button component is clicked. I used to be able to call `this.refs.myForm.focus()` which (given `myForm` as FormComponent) was written to call `.focus()` on the first form field inside. However, I've refactored and abstracted some behavior into a higher order component that wraps FormComponent so now, the `.focus()` method on FormComponent is intercepted by the wrapper component.

Using React 0.14.x (so I don't need `ReactDOM.findDOMnode()` for DOM components):

```
// FormComponent
class FormComponentBase extends React.Component {
    focus() {
        this.refs.firstField.focus();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form ...>
                <input ref="firstField" />
            </form>
        );
     }
}

// Wraps FormComponent in a wrapper component with abstracted/reusable functionality
const FormComponent = hocWrapper(FormComponent);

// OtherComponent
class OtherComponent extends React.Component {
    handleClick(ev) {
        // ERROR This doesn't work because the hocWrapper component is intercepting the .focus() call
        this.refs.myForm.focus();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Focus</button>
                <FormComponent ref="myForm" />
            </div>
        );
     }
}
```

Passing a `focus` prop and managing the state of whether the form's first element is focused in `OtherComponent` seems ludicrous. I know you can create `get`/`set` properties using `defineProperty` (or something like that) where accessing an instance property calls a method under the hood to generate the result, but does JS have something like Ruby's `missingMethod` or PHP's `__call` where I can define a catch-all method on my `hocWrapper` that just passes method calls through to the wrapped component? I've run into this issue before with calling other methods through HOC wrapper components but I think I just defined a pass-thru method of the same name on the HOC wrapper (which I'm fairly certain is the wrong way).

Comment: Is `autoFocus` sufficient here?

Comment: Negative. `autoFocus` is meant for when the page initially loads. I need to programmatically focus on a field anytime after initial page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than passing focus state down, you can pass the ref up fairly easily with the ref callback function. [Here's a fiddle illustrating](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/39177/)

```
class FormComponentBase extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form ...>
         <input ref={node => this.props.passNode(node)} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

class OtherComponent extends React.Component {
  receiveNode(node) {
    if (!this.state.node) this.setState({ node })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.state.node.focus()}>Focus</button>
        <FormComponent passNode={this.receiveNode} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE: a more idiomatic way that doesn't pass the node up. [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zys1pkyx/1/)**

```
var FormComponentBase = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <input ref={ node => 
      node && this.props.shouldFocus && node.focus()
    }/>
  }
})

var OtherComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { shouldFocus: false }
  },

  toggleFocus(node) {
    // toggle for demonstration
    this.setState({ shouldFocus: !this.state.shouldFocus })
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.toggleFocus() }>focus</button>
        <Child shouldFocus={this.state.shouldFocus} />
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: I actually used something similar on this same component in a previous iteration, but it seemed like a React anti-pattern since everything is supposed to flow down the render tree. Am I wrong in that perception?

Comment: I don't think this breaks the virtues of React. Lots of components work together in a circular fashion, passing down callback functions and sending in arguments back to the parent. The most robust way is passing down focus value from parent / redux, but that can get very verbose if you have many elements, so may not be worth it.

Comment: or for that matter, doing something like `<input ref={ node => this.props.shouldFocus && node.focus() } />`. That actually seems like a pretty easy way come to think of it and you don't have to pass anything back up.

Comment: For your `shouldFocus` example, that would mean I need to track the state in `OtherComponent` of when it would set `shouldFocus` to `true` and I'd need to then set it to `false` when the field blurs. Sounds to me like a downward spiral to madness. It's already fun tracking the open state of modals in some places in my app.

Comment: The button doesn't toggle the focus. It just sets the focus when clicked and that's it. So your original solution better addresses the problem. If you revert it, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Well... nothing's stopping you from doing `document.querySelector().focus()`. I think you can choose a few options from easiest to more robust.